# Counting number of points in each polygon

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I have 2 tables,

points: which has two columns latitude(float) and longitude(float).

polygon: which has two columns polygon_id(int) and geom(the shape of the polygon)

I want to print out number of points that are contained in each polygon_id.

I could figure out how to get the polygon_id that contain one point but couldn't progress further.

```
SELECT polygon.id
FROM polygon
WHERE st_contains(geom, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(120.32155 -33.843322)', 4326)) = true
```

I wanted to use latitude and longitude from the points table, however,

```
ST_GeomFromText('POINT(points.latitude points.longitude)
```

Did not work.

The expected results are having polygon_id and the points that the polygon_id contains for each row. Since there are 100 polygons, I'm expecting 100 rows.

Comment: How can the points table not have a reference to what polygon each point belongs to? I have no knowledge about this kind of database, I am just curious.

Comment: Hi @JoakimDanielson I believe the intent is simply to use the geometries from table `polygon` as a parameter to count the points on table `points`. They don't actually relate... at least not with the info we've got :-D Have a nice Sunday

Comment: points must be declared as `long lat`, not `lat long`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're missing is [`ST_MakePoint`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakePoint.html).

Considering your table structure and the following samples, which consist of a polygon and two overlapping points ..

```
CREATE TABLE polygon (id int, geom geometry);
INSERT INTO polygon VALUES (1,'POLYGON((120.20 -33.75,120.43 -33.75,120.43 -33.88,120.20 -33.88,120.20 -33.75))'::geometry);

CREATE TABLE points (lon numeric, lat numeric);
INSERT INTO points VALUES (120.32,-33.84);
INSERT INTO points VALUES (120.39, -33.85);
```

[image]

.. execute the following query:

```
SELECT polygon.id,COUNT(points.lon)
FROM polygon,points
WHERE ST_Contains(geom, ST_MakePoint(lon,lat))
GROUP BY polygon.id

 id | count 
----+-------
  1 |     2
(1 row)
```

I would recommend you to not store latitude and longitude in different columns. Storing points as `geometry` or `geography` is always the best choice in PostgreSQL/PostGIS.

Comment: Do you also need to specify the SRID of the point? Certainly doesn't hurt... i.e st_setsrid(ST_MakePoint(lon,lat),4326)

Comment: Certainly doesn't hurt! :) WGS84 is the default SRS in case nothing is provided, but your're right... it can be misleading. Good point.